# how to send object array in ext js 4 to server side?

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

i  am working in extjs4 MVC where I have been working on task to create question answer page functionality.There are 4 questions to be displayed with there options.I have getting all the selected questions and answers in controller.But I didnot know how to send to srver side using  models method.I am getting stuck at this point.

Here is my some controller code
1)

```
check:function()
    {
        console.log("Inside check function.");
        //creating objects in javascript
          var obj=new Object();
          for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)
          {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i); 
                var radio = "";  
                for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    if (inputs[j].checked) {
                        name = inputs[j].name;
                        value  = inputs[j].value;
                        //obj[i].name1=name;
                        obj[i]={'questionId':name,'option':value};
                        console.log("questionId="+name +" value="+ value);
                        console.log("object name="+ obj[i].questionId+" Object value="+obj[i].option);
                    }// End of if statment
                }// End of inner for loop
          }//End of outer for loop

    }// End of check function
```

2)here is I have getting some output in firebug

```
questionId=1 value=Aus QbqnsController.js:39
questionId=2 value=india QbqnsController.js:39
questionId=3 value=England QbqnsController.js:39
questionId=4 value=Srilanka
```

Actually i want to use model class methods save() . but how can I use it.
please give me some suggestions.

3)here is my model classs

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idproperty:'questionId',//fields property first position pk.
    fields: ['questionId','question','languageId','userId','creationTime','questionStatusId','keyword'],
    hasMany:{
            model:'Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsoptionModel',
            foreignKey:'questionId',
            name:'options',
        },


        proxy:
        {
            type:'ajax',
            api:
            {
                    read:'http://localhost/balaee/balaee/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/setuseranswer',
                    create:'http://localhost/balaee/balaee/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/setuseranswer',
            },//end of api
            reader:
            {
                    type:'json',
            },//end of reader
            writer:
            {
                    type:'json',
                    root:'records',
            },//End of writer
        }   

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ext MVC and you're questions are `model` instances stored inside a `store`, you can use `store.sync()` which will batch the data in different states (add, edit, deletes etc) and sync them with the relevant store or model proxy url, or the api urls specified.

This has the benefit of sending arrays of objects back in a single request, but then of course you need to separate them on the server side before processing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you can send them using  Ext.Ajax.request

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({

      url: 'your_server_page.php ',
        params: { 
           Your_Object_Name  : JSON.stringify(Your_Object_Array)
       }                                        
});
```

Comment: thanks. I am using MVC. so which method of model should I call.please give me some information.